Is there some link between analytic continuation and potential theory?
It seems like the analytic continuation of a function has a lot in common with the process of trying to define a potential for a vector field (or a differential 1-form). In particular, an analytic element $\mathcal E_0$ (i.e. a disc together with a power series convergent in that disc) which can be continued unconditionally in a simply connected domain $D$ defines a unique analytic function in $D$. Similarly, a closed 1-form $\omega$ is always locally the differential of somescalar field $\phi$, and $\phi$ can be consistenly extended in the domain of $\omega$ by integrating $\omega$ along paths if the domain is simply connected. In both cases, the "continuation" doesn't work in general if the domain isn't simply connected, leading to "multiple values".
So, is there by chance some precise sense in which an analytic function is the "potential" of something, and the analytic continuation is analogous to the "integration" of that something?

@QiaochuYuan Yes, I'm familiar. Please go ahead :)

Ah, never mind, I thought you were asking something a bit different. Anyway, there's still a relationship. Let's consider the archetypal case of analytic continuation of the logarithm $\log z$: this corresponds to understanding holomorphic solutions of the differential equation $\frac{df}{dz} = \frac{1}{z}$, or equivalently, to integrating the holomorphic $1$-form $\frac{dz}{z}$. We can construct solutions locally by integrating along paths in the complex plane not passing through the origin but globally there is monodromy.

@QiaochuYuan Thanks! Does this work for square roots, though? It looks like the derivative of a square root is still multivalued.

Yeah, that example is less nice because the derivative is still multivalued. I don't know if there's a nice general statement here. I guess instead of thinking about analytically continuing $\sqrt{z}$ directly you think about analytically continuing $\log \sqrt{z} = \frac{1}{2} \log z$, then take the exponential.
